# Where to practice violin 5 hours every day in Paris?

Tags: paris, tips-and-tricks, music

I'll travel to Paris, France in June. For my musical studies, I need to practice violin 5 hours every day (~ 84-103 dB), alone. Is there any place I could use in Paris for such purpose, if possible at a reasonable price?

Comment: Go to the park. Any park will do. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO That's indeed an option, a trumpetist friend used to do it between Cite U and perif,  but often a bit too much environment noise for violin and there might be some rainy day. So I'd rather avoid it :)

Comment: I was going to say the Luxembourg Gardens because there's a gazebo and a stage for inclement weather.  Also, the acoustics on the footpath underneath the Pont Neuf are superb for that sort of thing...   But I think Joe has a better answer.

Comment: @GayotFow Make that into an answer. The Pont Neuf is a **great** suggestion!

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks, I agree with Jo, good outside spots are interesting as well and worth an answer!

Comment: IMO, there is a difference between practicing and playing; if you practice scales (and/or other more technical aspects of violin playing) then playing in a parc will not be fun for the other people around; if your 5 hours is simply playing, why not; but be ready to be asked to leave

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Rent a (Solo) Music Studio

Since you mention the need to be alone, a dedicated music studio comes to mind. A quick google search revealed [Studio Luna Rossa in the 13th Arrondissement](http://www.studiolunarossa.com/Luna_Rossa-Studio_de_repetition_a_Paris/Studio_Luna_Rossa.html) and [Maison de la Musique in Neuilly-Sur-Seine 92200](http://www.lamaisondelamusique.fr/location-de-studios-de-repetitions). Both of these offer small solo studios for something around 6-7`EUR` per hour, during both weekdays (off-peak and peak hours) and weekends. Whether this is considered as cheap is up to you to. :) There must be more music studios available for rental out there. These are just two examples. To find more you might want to try querying your favourite search engine for *salle de musique* and/or *studio de répétition* (French for music studio).

### Parks and Kiosques

If you decide one day that you want to see something else other than soundproofing foam in Paris, you could head to any park, set up your gear on the grass and go nuts. Indeed it is not uncommon to see random art performers rehearsing in the Parisian parks. [Here is a map of all the parks in Paris and Ile-de-France metropolitan area.](http://meslieux.paris.fr/principaux-parcs-et-jardins)

Moreover some parks have dedicated music gazebos (*kiosques* in French) with great acoustics. These are usually free to use. Note that from May to October some kiosques will be taken by [the annual Kiosques en Musique musical event](http://www.paris.fr/pratique/paris-au-vert/musique-cote-jardins/kiosques-en-musique/rub_5598_stand_10081_port_11960), [whose full 2015 program can be found here](https://filer.paris.fr/quefaire/uploads/files/KIOSQUES%20EN%20MUSIQUE%20-%20programme%202015%20web.pdf). If you wish to use the kiosques you'll want to coordinate yourself with these events. [Here is a map of all the kiosques in the Parisian parks.](https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zZ5Q6-_dENvA.kKc8LwAWdvtI) Below is a picture of the kiosque at the Parc du square Necker:

[image: kiosque at the Parc du square Necker]

*<sup>Le kiosque à musique du square Necker, [Micheline](http://www.kiosquesdumonde.net/), Fair use</sup>*

#### Park Regulations and Musical Instruments

Note that is is technically forbidden to make noise and disturb other park users, as per [the parks rules and regulations established by the Mairie de Paris](http://api-site-cdn.paris.fr/images/155185.pdf). Moreover these explicitly mention noise arising from playing instruments:

> Sont interdits les bruits gênants par leur intensité, leur durée, leur
>   fréquence ou leur caractère agressif, en particuliers ceux produits par
>   les instruments de musique et de percussion et par la diffusion de
>   musique amplifiée, sauf dérogation.

Whilst this does indeed mean that you need to ask the Mairie de Paris for authorisation to play an instrument in the park, in my humble opinion you should be able to play freely so long as you don't disturb others around you. Whether violin music is a nuisance due to its intensity, duration, frequency or aggressive character (translating the afore-mentioned rules) is up for discussion. In any case, keep in mind that you are doing something forbidden and that therefore people might ask you to move or stop.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to go and play music in Paris Parks. As the official rules (http://www.paris.fr/portail/viewmultimediadocument?multimediadocument-id=16780) mentions in article 10, it is not allowed to play music in Parks. Musical instruments are explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Besides "salle de musiques", I suggest searching for "studio de répétition". That is an acoustically isolated room that you can rent for an hourly fee.

Comment: @audionuma You have a point. I will add that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The metro stations were a good option when I was in Paris 40 years ago.

Comment: I considered writing this answer myself, but decided not to, having never been in Paris, myself. +1, in any event :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, playing music in the metro requires a special license by the RATP that being much demanded cannot be obtained easily. http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/c_18839/preparez-vous-pour-les-auditions-des-musiciens-du-metro/